# Dissatisfaction with/at - which one is correct?

Tags: prepositions

> I am writing to express my complete dissatisfaction **with** the meal
>   I was served last night.
>
> I am writing to express my complete dissatisfaction **at** the meal I
>   was served last night.

Which one is correct? It seems to me that the first sentence is correct and the second is wrong, but according to [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dissatisfaction?q=dissatisfaction) it's correct to use **at**:

> She expressed deep dissatisfaction at the way the interview had been conducted.

I'm not a native speaker of English so I'm asking the natives what they think about it.Is "at" the replacement of "with"?

Comment: As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+dissatisfaction+*+the+way&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Chis%20dissatisfaction%20%2A%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhis%20dissatisfaction%20with%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhis%20dissatisfaction%20at%20the%20way%3B%2Cc0) shows, both prepositions (***with*** and ***at***) are used between ***dissatisfaction*** and ***the way***. They both *mean* exactly the same, but ***with*** is (increasingly) more common.

Comment: What about "at" the meal? Is it correct?

Comment: You shouldn't assume there's only one "correct" preposition for any given context. But *idiomatically*, it's true that the preference for *dissatisfaction **with** X* is even stronger where ***X*** is a straightforward ***noun*** (such as ***the meal***). We're more likely to use *dissatisfaction **at** X* where ***X*** identifies an ***action*** (perhaps adverbially identifying ***how*** that action was carried out). But these are fine points that will vary from speaker to speaker (so as a learner, you should probably just stick to ***with*** in all cases; you won't go far wrong).

Answer (score 2):

For me, these are both fine:

'I am writing to express my complete dissatisfaction with the meal I was served last night.'

'She expressed deep dissatisfaction at the way the interview had been conducted.'

Whereas this sentence sounds very wrong:

'I am writing to express my complete dissatisfaction at the meal I was served last night.'

As a native English speaker, it is often hard to think about the reason why something sounds right or wrong.  I am wondering if you would use 'with' when you are talking about a noun, and 'at' when you are talking about a verb.  I suspect there will be a counter-example though!

Alan.